# SQL: Trying to order a column by descending order while ignoring two records on top

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to order by column and I want to ignore couple of records which should be on top and order by remaining records. Any quick help is much appreciated. This is what I have so far. Thank you.

```
 select * 
 from table  
 order by case when column  in (1,2) then order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: i mean i want to ignore my condition rows on top and order other rows

Comment: Is this SQL 2008 or 2012? It matters since OFFSET FETCH can do that for you

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you're looking for is this:

```
Select      * 
From        Table  
Order By    Case When Column In (1,2) Then 0 Else 1 End, 
            Column;
```

I added the `Column` as the secondary sort because you mention:

> and order by remaining records

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table  
order by case when column  in (1,2) then 1 else 2 end asc, column desc
```

This is called a conditional sort or order. Essentially you give explicit values to those which you want on the top and then follow on with your normal sorting.